# see console output of GUI C++ application in MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm working on an application in MS Visual Studio 2010, which opens an OpenGL window and renders things. However, I would like to see the output of various prinf's I have in my code. How do I enable / view the console output?

Comment: @Hans Passant: could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use OutputDebugString() to get output displayed in the Visual Studio Output window. Linking your own version of printf is the easiest way to avoid editing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think running it via the command line would do the job.

Do not use an external program like Start though, simply enter full path of the executable file on command prompt.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to get the dependencies / libraries / whatever correct. A box pops up and says "The program can't start because SDL.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". Running it works fine from inside MSVC